# How to receive ETH in a smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, cryptocurrency

i am working on an ico and i got this code, the crowdsale was with dai token but i want to work with ether,
how can i do that ?

```
IERC20 public dai = IERC20(0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F);
function buy(uint etherAmount)
    external
    icoActive() {
    require(
      etherAmount >= minPurchase && etherAmount <= maxPurchase, 
      'have to buy between minPurchase and maxPurchase'
    );
    uint tokenAmount = etherAmount.div(price);
    
    require(
      tokenAmount <= availableTokens, 
      'Not enough tokens left for sale'
    );
    dai.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), etherAmount);
    token.mint(address(this), tokenAmount);
    sales[msg.sender] = Sale(
        msg.sender,
        tokenAmount,
        false
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `payable` function modifier. See [documentation how to receive Ether in smart contracts](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#receive-ether-function).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `receive()` fallback function to receive ETH in your smart contract.

Add this function to your smart contract.

```
receive() external payable {}
```